# JavaScript Syntax for creating a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a piece of code that is built like this:

```
var Template = function() { return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <document>
  //other stuff
  </document>`
}
```

The function is used in another file by doing

```
var resource = Template.call(self);
```

Coming from a C++/Objective-C/Swift background, I am guessing it's a function named `Template` and returns whatever the stuff inside is. Could someone advise me what this construct is supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, that's a function expression. The thing inside of it is an ES6 template string (doing string interpolation).

Comment: This thread might help you - [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the body of a script,

```
var x = function() { };
```

is equivalent to

```
function x() { }
```

as the first is a variable declaration with a function body assigned, it should be terminated by a `;` other than a function definition.

The reason doing something like this is, that the variable scope applies. Having this inside a function

```
function a() {


      var x = function () { ... };

}
```

means, that function `x` isn't defined outside of `a`; calling `x` outside of `a` results in a reference error.